# Unable to call Android Kitkat Class?

Tags: android, methods

I am not able call **KitKat** class like when I am going to call `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. I am getting a error

```
ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

and for `takePersistableUriPermission(Uri, int)`

```
The method takePersistableUriPermission(Uri, int) is 
undefined for the type ContentResolver
```

Comment: try adding support library from android tools

Comment: What IDE are you using? What build system are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double check that your project target build is using Android 4.4 (SDK 19), in Eclipse this can be done by:

Right clicking the project and click "Properties". Then select "Android" from the tree on the left. You can then select the target version on the right.

If you don't see 4.4 as an option, open up the SDK manager and make sure you have installed Android 4.4 KitKat

Comment: Thanks its worked but which build version should I Use? The android open source project or google apli?

Comment: You should always start with the Android API's. The Google API's include all of the google maps and other Google specific libraries. The Android ones just contain the core libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio and gradle build system it should automatically highlight it for you. Obviously is that you haven't indicated for compiler to use 19 version of sdk. Assuming you're using gradle you should add `buildToolsVersion "19.0"` and `compileSdkVersion 19`. Example of `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: "android"

android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.0"
    compileSdkVersion 19
}
```

After that don't forget to sync gradle settings: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

And as @Glenn-- has pointed - don't forget to update `AndroidManifest.xml`